# Facebook Graph API - Get a page's visitor posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.5

How do I get to the posts that are put under 'VISITOR POSTS' on a Facebook page? I have been unable to find these in the Graph API and am starting to wonder whether the API grants access to the at all.I tried:

- `v2.5/me/feed?fields=reactions` = `Reactions read API requires version v2.6 or higher`
- `v2.5/me/feed?fields=comments` = Not the comments I want
- `v2.5/me/comments` = `Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type (Page)`

Is it even possible to access `VISITOR POSTS`?

Comment: I'd like to know this as well.